# Getting form data in a jsp and retrieve that data from servlet with of mvc from sql database and show the result table in another jsp?

Tags: java, sql, model-view-controller, web-applications, glassfish

Well as I described I have a MVC model implementation using glassfish and NetBeans support. I am fairly new into this area of learning and finding it difficult to understand how to implement a search bar in the web app and retrieve that data using the servlet and model and daos . The coding is as follow:

JSP file where search textbox is placed :

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Doctor Dashboard</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0afbc9b86d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/styles.css" />
        </head>
        <body id="body">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="navbar">
                    <div class="nav_icon" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar__left">
    
                        <a class="active_link" href="#">Profile</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar__right">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img width="30" src="assets/avatar.svg" alt="" />
                            <!-- <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <main>
                    <div class="main__container">
                        <form method="POST" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Dreport/patientrecordinfo" style="align-items:center">
                            <div style="align-items: center;">
                                <h1>Patient Records</h1>
                                <p style="margin-top: 2rem; align-items: center">Enter the Patient ID:</p>
//Place where the data to be retrieved from
                                <input  style=" width:20%; height:40px; display: inline-block;  background:whitesmoke;"type="text" placeholder="Patient ID..." name="patientid" required><br>
                                <input style="margin-top:2rem;"  required type="checkbox" name="confirm" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Agree to Protect Customer privacy
                                <br>
                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    <button style="background-color:blueviolet; color: white; padding: 14px 20px; margin: 8px 0; border: none; cursor: pointer;width: 30%;
                                            opacity: 0.9;" type="submit" class="signupbtn">Search</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </main>
    
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <div class="sidebar__title">
                        <div class="sidebar__img">
                            <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/imgs/Doctor.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" alt="logo" />
                            <h1>&nbsp;&nbsp; Welcome Doctor,<br>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp; Nimesh Kottawatta
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <i
                            onclick="closeSidebar()"
                            class="fa fa-times"
                            id="sidebarIcon"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                            ></i>
                    </div>
                    <!--SIDE_BAR-->
                    <div class="sidebar__menu">
                        <div class="sidebar__link ">
                            <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Dreport/Dashboard">Dashboard</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sidebar__link active_menu_link">
                            <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
                            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Dreport">Check Report</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sidebar__link">
                            <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>
                            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Dreport/reportupdate">Update Report</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sidebar__logout">
                            <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
                            <a href="#">Log out</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

And the Servlet :

```
package com.primavera.controllers;

import com.primavera.Managers.StaffManager;
import com.primavera.entities.Patient;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(name = "Dreport", urlPatterns = {"/Dreport","/Dreport/Dashboard","/Dreport/reportupdate","/Dreport/patientrecordinfo"})
public class Dreport extends HttpServlet {

    //Default constructor
    public Dreport(){}
    
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
          RequestDispatcher dispatcher=null;
        // 1. Get data from the Model
        if (request.getServletPath().contains("/Dashboard")) {
           dispatcher= request.getRequestDispatcher("/DoctorDashboard.jsp");
        } else if (request.getServletPath().contains("/reportupdate")){
            dispatcher= request.getRequestDispatcher("/DUpdateReport.jsp");
        }else if (request.getServletPath().contains("/patientrecordinfo")){
        //1.Get data info from model  
        
        int user_Id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("patientid"));//Taking doctor inserting id
        
        List<Patient> list = new ArrayList<Patient>();//Creating a list to hold data
        
        list=StaffManager.getInstance().getPatientInfo(user_Id);//MVC method implementation for Searching patient
        
        request.setAttribute("list", list);
       
        //view 
        RequestDispatcher rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("records.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
         
        }
        else {
            dispatcher= request.getRequestDispatcher("/DReport.jsp");
        }
        // 2. Forwarding to View
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

   
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
    
    
}
```

The model: Manager class :

```
package com.primavera.Managers;

import com.primavera.daos.PatientDao;
import com.primavera.entities.Doctor;
import com.primavera.entities.Nurse;
import com.primavera.entities.Patient;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StaffManager {
    //Creating a singletance instance

    private static StaffManager instance = new StaffManager();
    private static PatientDao dao= new PatientDao();

    private StaffManager() {
    }

    public static StaffManager getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    //Method implementations

    public List <Patient> getPatientInfo(int user_Id) {
      return dao.getPatient(user_Id);
    }

}
```

And the Dao is :

```
package com.primavera.daos;

import com.primavera.entities.Patient;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PatientDao {

    DatabaseConnection db= new DatabaseConnection();
    Patient patient = new Patient();
    
    //Method implemetation for getting Patient records by Doctor
    public List <Patient> getPatient(int user_Id) {
    
    List <Patient> list = new ArrayList<Patient>();    
    ResultSet rs=null;
     try{   
    PreparedStatement pst =db.conn().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE user_id = ?"); // ? = placeholder
    pst.setInt(1, user_Id); // Bind the value to the placeholder
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
  while(rs.next()){
  patient.setName(rs.getString("user_name"));
  patient.setGender(rs.getString("user_gender"));
  list.add(patient);
  }
    
     }
     catch(SQLException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
    
     return list;
    }
     
}
```

And the another jsp for now i would the data to be visible in :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Patient Report</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <c:if test="${list!=null}">
    <table>
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="record">
            <tr>
                <td>${record.patient_Id}</td>
                <td>${record.name }</td>
                <td>${record.gender }</td>
                <td>${record.DOB }</td>
                <td>${record.phone }</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much in advance for that supports me to solve it .

Answer (score 0):

Well I discovered my errors there were few first I had tried to retrieve data from the doGet method in servlet and not the doPost which was a huge error since the method that form uses to send data is POST, some basic correction were as below :

```
 @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       if (request.getServletPath().contains("patientrecordinfo")) {
           // Calling doPost to retrieve form data
           int user_Id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("patientid"));//Taking doctor inserting id
           List list = new ArrayList<>();//Creating a list to hold data
           list = StaffManager.getInstance().getPatientInfo(user_Id);//MVC method implementation for Searching patient

           request.setAttribute("list", list);
           request.getRequestDispatcher("/records.jsp").forward(request, response);
       }
    }
```

And class implementations were :

Manager class method :

```
public List getPatientInfo(int user_Id) {
      return dao.getPatient(user_Id);
    }
```

And DAO:

```
 public List getPatient(int user_Id) {

        List list = new ArrayList();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hms", "root", "");
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE user_id = ?"); // ? = placeholder
            pst.setInt(1, user_Id); // Bind the value to the placeholder
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs != null) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Patient patient = new Patient();
                    patient.setPatient_Id(rs.getString("user_id"));
                    patient.setName(rs.getString("user_name"));
                    patient.setGender(rs.getString("user_gender"));
                    patient.setDOB(rs.getDate("user_DOB"));
                    patient.setPhone(rs.getInt("phone"));
                    patient.setSickness(rs.getString("user_sickeness"));
                    patient.setAllegeries(rs.getString("user_allergies"));
                    patient.setSymptoms(rs.getString("user_specail_request"));
                    patient.setAddress(rs.getString("user_address"));
                    list.add(patient);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Hope someone would benefit as myself I'm a beginner to java MVC might not be the most elegant way , would love for anyone ideas to improve as well.